# Dynamically creating resources in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How do I send the resource block(ex:resource "aws volume attachment" "ebs att") as an input to tf file

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
device_name = "/dev/sdh"
volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}"
instance_id = "${aws_instance.example.id}"
force_detach = "true"
}
```

Assume,below is my terraform .tf file

```
provider "aws" {
region     = "${var.region}"
access_key = "${var.access_key}"
secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"

}

resource "aws_key_pair" "deployer" {
key_name   = "testkey-${var.hostname}"
public_key = "${file(var.public_key_path)}"
}
```

For this file,il have to send the resource block->

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att"
```

Such that the final .tf file looks like

```
provider "aws" {
region     = "${var.region}"
access_key = "${var.access_key}"
secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"

}

resource "aws_key_pair" "deployer" {
key_name   = "testkey-${var.hostname}"
public_key = "${file(var.public_key_path)}"
}
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
device_name = "/dev/sdh"
volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}"
instance_id = "${aws_instance.example.id}"
force_detach = "true"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide a larger, worked example and explain what you're trying to do here? Also are you using Terraform 0.12+?

Comment: Ok

I have edited the issue

Usually  terraform allows us to input the variable value outside the tf file without being explicitly given in tf file

Is there a way to provide resource block as the same way we do for variables??

Comment: Why would you want to do this instead of just adding that volume attachment in a `.tf` file in that directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not be able to dynamically add new resources with terraform scripts alone(*why I am telling "**alone**" is that in my case I have used python classes as configuration and generate terraform files from them dynamically and run apply command from python script*)

You can achieve this in another way by adding count to the resource and set a default variable value to 0 so that resource won't get created usually, unless u specifically set the count value to 1

```
variable "create_ebs_resource" {
  type = number
  default = 0
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.example.id}"
  force_detach = "true"
  count = var.create_ebs_resource
}
```

Then run apply command as 
`terraform apply -var="create_ebs_resource=1"` if you would like to create resource else simply run `terraform apply`

Comment: That's Perfect Sajeer,

Thanks a lot for the response